# How to add example based parameter to custom keras loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I want to have custom loss function in keras, which has a parameter that is different for each training example.

```
from keras import backend as K

def my_mse_loss_b(b):
     def mseb(y_true, y_pred):
         return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)) + b
     return mseb
```

I read [here](https://petamind.com/advanced-keras-custom-loss-functions/#A_custom_loss_function_with_parameters) that y_true and y_pred are always passed to the loss function so you need to create wrapper function.

```
model.compile(loss=my_mse_loss_b(df.iloc[:,2]), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The problem is that when I fit the model there is an error as the function assumes the passed parameters will be as long as the batch. I on the other hand want each example to have there own parameter.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [20] vs. [10000]
     [[node gradients/loss_2/dense_3_loss/mseb/weighted_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at C:\Users\flis1\Miniconda3\envs\Automate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_1129]
Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Incompatible shapes it says. 20 is the batch size and 10000 is the size of my train dataset and the size of all the parameters.

I can fit the model if I the parameter I add is the size of the batch, but as I said I want the parameter to be passed on  an example basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, because your parameter `b` is tightly coupled to its training example, it would make sense to make it part of the ground truth. You could rewrite your loss function like the following:

```
def mseb(y_true, y_pred):
    y_t, b = y_true[0], y_true[1]
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_t)) + b
```

and then train your model with

```
model.compile(loss=mseb)
b = df.iloc[:,2]
model.fit(X,(y,b))
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out myself, the only problem I see you have to adjust all the metric functions.

Comment: I hope you guys are still around. I'm currently trying the same thing. Unfortunately, y_t and b have different shapes within my loss function resulting in a slicing error. Shapes in fit(): y=(1,8700,18), b=(1,8700,1); shapes in loss function: (y_t, b)=(32,18); batch size is 32. So it seems like y_true does not contain (y,b) but 32 samples of y. What am I missing?

Comment: @CLRW97 it's hard to diagnose in a comment so I suggest you ask a question if you need to. Make sure that you're passing the right tuple (y,b) to your fit function.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I've double-checked it but couldn't find any difference. I ended up writing my own model class with a customized train_step() method. It works fine.